# Play Framework 2.5 : method mat in trait Filter of type => akka.stream.Materializer is not defined

Tags: scala, playframework

I am migrating from Play 2.4 to 2.5. I am getting an error as below:

MyOverridingFilter  object creation impossible, since method mat in trait Filter of type => akka.stream.Materializer is not defined.

My code is as below:

```
   object Global extends WithFilters {
/*some code here*/
override def doFilter(next: EssentialAction): EssentialAction = {
    Filters(super.doFilter(next), MyOverridingFilter)
  }
}

object MyOverridingFilter extends Filter {
}
```

Play Version: 2.5.0
akka-stream : 2.5.19

Can someone please help me in resolving this.

Thanks